# Timer keeps working after invalidate() and nil

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I have this timer:

```
class InstallationViewController: BaseViewController {

   var precentageTimer: Timer!
}
```

In the same class I am starting the timer like so:

```
               self.precentageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                self.network.getClibrationPercentage(success: { (info, percent) in
                    self.isAnalysisCompleted(percent: percent)
                    self.precentageLbl.text = "\(percent)%"
                    self.instructionsLbl.text = info
                    self.precentageLbl.isHidden = false
                }, failure: { (error) in
                    print(error)
                })
            })
```

I have also this method for dissmisal of tasks:

```
 func dissmissAllTasks() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    self.setCalibrationEnableTimer?.invalidate()
    self.setCalibrationEnableTimer = nil
    self.snapShotTimer?.invalidate()
    self.snapShotTimer = nil
    self.precentageTimer?.invalidate()
    self.precentageTimer = nil
}
```

It happens when I am stepping through viewWillDisappear like so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    dissmissAllTasks()
 }
```

But when I am going to other VC I can see this timer keeps on going.
I have checked the dissmissAllTasks() called, and I can see the timer is nil.

Why the timer keeps on going?

Comment: In what function is the code that schedules the timer? Perhaps you call it more than once and create multiple timers.

Comment: @rmaddy the precentageTimer starts when a button pushed and that is the only place i call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost certainly assigning `precentageTimer` twice without invalidating it in between. This is a very common mistake. The function that includes `self.precentageTimer =` is probably being called multiple times before `viewWillDisappear` is called. Since you tied it to a button press, it's likely happening if the button is pressed twice.

The usual solution is to add a `willSet` to `percentageTimer` like this (and you do not want `percentageTimer` to be `!`; it absolutely should be `?` because it can be legitimately nil):

```
var precentageTimer: Timer? {
    willSet {
        percentageTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: The button can be push 3 times yet every time changes the tag and thus why the method called once.
the will set , will set it invalidate in when the VC loads ?
how can that help?

Comment: I don't know what this means. Which "tag" are you referring to, and what you do mean by "the method called once?" I am certain that you're calling this line of code more than once before you invalidate, or that you have multiple copies of the view controller. Given your symptoms, those are the two causes that happen all the time. Put a breakpoint on the assignment line and see if it's ever called when the timer is already set.

Comment: Thats what i did... the line called once and repeats because of the timer config (as i wanted)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you create and invalidate timer in the same thread.

Also you have `self` captured with strong reference in the closure so I believe the reference to your timer is still alive.
You get something from server in like 0.1 seconds with repeats and all your requests seems to be alive too.

Comment: Is that what you are suggestion? :
                self.precentageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self](timer) in
                    self?.network.getClibrationPercentage(success: { (info, percent) in
                        self?.isAnalysisCompleted(percent: percent)
                        self?.precentageLbl.text = "\(percent)%"
                        self?.instructionsLbl.text = info
                        self?.precentageLbl.isHidden = false

Comment: it should work I believe
but it seems to me that it’s about threads

Comment: The weak self that i am doing is what you where thinking about?

Comment: Not only thing but yes. I'm a bit confused with your comments.

Comment: which of them?
i will try to explain my self

Comment: I can't get what you really can't understand from my answer. I'm not sure in `self` capture here but give it a try.

Comment: i am asking if i am using in weak self correct as showed you in the first comment

Comment: If this doesn't help you then make sure you're creating and invalidating timer in the same thread and see Rob Napier's answer - it seems to help you.